# implicit conversion of an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, scala

I have a case class called Point defined as follows:

```
case class Point(x: Double, y: Double)
```

and a functions that takes an array of points:

```
def f(coords: Array[Point]) ...
```

I want to be able to implictly pass an array of double arrays to my function. To achieve this I have defined the following two implicit functions:

```
implicit def arrayToPoint(a: Array[Double]) = new Point(a(0), a(1)) 
implicit def arraysToPoints(a: Array[Array[Double]]) = a map(p => Point(p(0), p(1)))
```

My questions is is there any way I can achieve this with just a single implict conversion function to simplify matters?

And as a related question what would be the best approach if I wanted to be able to pass an Array of Ints instead of Doubles?

Regards

Des

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `arraysToPoints` is superfluous. You could use a view bound on the array argument for your method `f` and add the conversion to the companion object of `Point`, like so:

```
object Point {
  implicit def arrayToPoint[A](a: Array[A])(implicit view: A => Double): Point =
    Point(a(0), a(1))
}
case class Point(x: Double, y: Double)

def f[P](coords: Array[P])(implicit view: P => Point): Unit = coords.foreach { p =>
  println(p: Point)
}

f(Array(Point(1, 2), Point(2, 3)))
f(Array(Array(1.0, 2.0), Array(3.0, 4.0)))
f(Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4)))
```

In order to allow both arrays of `Int` and `Double` to be covered, I have used a second view bound on the `arrayToPoint` method. Otherwise you would need two separate conversion methods for `Array[Int]` and `Array[Double]`.

You can read this definition of `f` as, "take an array of elements of a type `P` which can be viewed as type `Point`". One spot where the compiler looks for such views is the companion object of the target type, thus `object Point`. This is a good place for implicit methods.

---

The second possibility would be to use the [magnet pattern](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/). Instead of converting point by point with a view in `f`, you would create a single wrapper object at once. This is a bit prettier and for large arrays minimises the penalty on direct `Array[Double]` arguments (because you instantiate the wrapper once, but then do not need to call the view function any more). `arrayToPoint` is used whenever the array element type `A` once again can be viewed as a `Double`. This is true for `Double` itself of course, but also for `Int` which can be seen as a `Double` though what Scala calls numeric widening (e.g., you can say `val x: Double = 33` and the integer `33` is implicitly "widened" to a double).

```
object Points {
  implicit def direct(a: Array[Point]): Points =
    new Points {
      val peer = a
    }

  implicit def indirect[A](a: Array[Array[A]])(implicit view: A => Double): Points =
    new Points {
      lazy val peer = a.map { c => Point(c(0), c(1)) }
    }
}
trait Points {
  def peer: Array[Point]
}

def f(coords: Points): Unit = coords.peer.foreach(println)
```

This looks in the companion object for an implicit method from the argument type to the special magnet type `Points`. I use `lazy val` for the non-direct arrays so that we might save the actual conversion action if the `peer` method is not called.

Comment: In general, my advise would be to use view bounds rarely. I would use these conversions from arrays to `Point` only if you have them really all over the place. If you have only a few places where such conversion is needed, it is better to perform it explicitly (you can use the method `arrayToPoint` and just remove its `implicit` modifier). Especially when you are new to Scala, you can get quite confused with constructing too many implicit conversions, before you have fully understood when and in which scope they should be used. In Scala 2.10, the compiler even emits a warning.

Comment: And of course you can also use the <% notation rather than have to declare an explcit view bound conversion. ie ArrayToPoint[A <% Double](a: Array[A])